# Apps script weird behavior about loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I found a weird behavior when I debug a script on apps script.
I don't know why `var` and `const` behaved differently in apps script.

Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  Logger.log('loop with var')
  for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    var a=i%2
    Logger.log(a)
  }
  Logger.log('loop with const')
  for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    const b=i%2
    Logger.log(b)
  }
}
```

And the output:

```
[18-10-07 19:03:57:377 HKT] Starting execution
[18-10-07 19:03:57:384 HKT] Logger.log([loop with var, []]) [0 seconds]
[18-10-07 19:03:57:385 HKT] Logger.log([0.0, []]) [0 seconds]
[18-10-07 19:03:57:386 HKT] Logger.log([1.0, []]) [0 seconds]
[18-10-07 19:03:57:386 HKT] Logger.log([0.0, []]) [0 seconds]
[18-10-07 19:03:57:387 HKT] Logger.log([loop with const, []]) [0 seconds]
[18-10-07 19:03:57:387 HKT] Logger.log([0.0, []]) [0 seconds]
[18-10-07 19:03:57:388 HKT] Logger.log([0.0, []]) [0 seconds]
[18-10-07 19:03:57:388 HKT] Logger.log([0.0, []]) [0 seconds]
[18-10-07 19:03:57:390 HKT] Execution succeeded [0.005 seconds total runtime]
```

My expected result is `0 1 0` and `0 1 0`.

Comment: Did you mean `0 1 0` and `0 1 0`?

Comment: Quote:  "The value of a constant cannot change through reassignment, and it can't be redeclared"  [Link to Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Comment: @I'-'I Yes, you are right. I edited it.

Comment: Interestingly, an object that is a constant can have it's keys and values changed.

Comment: @SandyGood But they are `block-scoped`, so they could be redeclared in each iteration.

Comment: I guess `block-scope` doesn't work with `const` in apps-script... as it's based on ES3 with cherry picks from ES5+. You can `Logger.log(b)` outside the scope and it'll still log the last value... Hoisting is maintained... Probably only re-declarations are prohibited(sometimes silently, I guess).

Comment: I tried out this too on browser and via node too `for(var i = 0; i<3; i++) {const b = i%2; console.log(b)}`. Getting response as expected `0 1 0`. Are you sure you are getting `0 0 0`. If so then there's an issue with your `Logger.log`

Comment: There are plans to update the implementation of JavaScript in Apps Script to a newer version, but there is no announced date as to when that will happen.

Comment: I only advise using `const` in function scope in Apps Script. Block scope is supposedly valid, but Apps Script isn't exactly EMCAScript compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Although apps script appears to handle const in block scope, in fact the first value assigned to it is the one that sticks, so for example

```
for ( var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++ ) {
  const x = i;
}
```

x will always be 0. This is due to an implementation error in the JavaScript emulator (rhino).

There’s a full explanation here
http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gassnips/constsandscopes

And a complete summary of what works and what doesn’t on rhino here

http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gassnips/rhinoversion

Hopefully apps script JavaScript dialect will catch up,one day, but for the meantime avoid const except for single use assignments.